# Nesting or Referencing Queries in Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, nested

I'm having trouble understanding nested queries. I have a comments table and a posts table and I want to count the number of comments in a given date range for a given site. This part I can do fine, but if there are no comments on one of those dates in the date range then it just skips it.

So I found a query that builds the full date range and counts the number of comments against that.

```
SELECT drange.date, count(comm.id)
FROM
    (
        SELECT to_char(date_trunc('day', (current_date - offs)), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date 
        FROM generate_series(1, 7, 1) AS offs
    ) drange
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    comments comm ON (
        drange.date=to_char(date_trunc('day', comm.created_at), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    ) 
GROUP BY drange.date;
```

Now this returns what partially what I want, but doesn't of course doesn't factor in the posts table.

```
date         count
2016-01-11   2
2016-01-12   0
....
2016-01-07   1
```

So I know the `count(comm.id)` needs to reference `inner join posts`, but I can't get that to work while still keeping the full date ranges intact. The query below factors in the posts table, but gets rid of the rest of the dates

```
SELECT drange.date, count(comm.id)
FROM
    (
      SELECT to_char(date_trunc('day', (current_date - offs)), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date 
      FROM generate_series(1, 7, 1) AS offs
    ) drange
    LEFT OUTER JOIN comments comm ON (
        drange.date=to_char(date_trunc('day', comm.created_at), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    )
    INNER JOIN
    posts ON (comm.post_id = posts.id) 
WHERE posts.site_id = 35
GROUP BY drange.date;
```

Returns:

```
date        count
2016-01-07  1
```

So is there a correct way to combine these queries? I don't understand how to reference the inner join results. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe will be easier if you use [CTE's](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) If you already have a query working name it on a CTE and use it on a second query. CTE works exact as a subquery, but is easier to read, and you can reuse it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First move the date range series to the right side of the table expression. Second move the `where` condition to the `join` condition. Both moves will avoid the nulls exclusion happening in your query.

```
select g.d, count(c.id)
from
    comments c 
    inner join
    posts p on c.post_id = p.id and p.site_id = 35
    right join
    generate_series (
        current_date - 7, current_date, '1 day'
    ) g(d) on g.d = date_trunc('day', c.created_at)
group by g.d
```